# AngularJS, strange behavior, entering if statement even the expression is not true

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to do some action in my controller when the view is loaded. In my controller, I have the following code:

```
$scope.$on('$viewContentLoaded', function () {
//Here your view content is fully loaded !!
   if ($scope.hasErrors === true) {
     showError('Error message');
     $scope.errorMessage = 'error';
   }
});
```

Firstly, this event fires multiple times. I suppose it is due to angular digest cycle? But, the strange thing is, when I debug js in my Firefox, it comes to the logical expression and even when

```
$scope.hasErrors = false
```

it stops on the line

```
$scope.errorMessage = 'error';
```

Is this issue due to Firefox, or something else?

Comment: did you try with `$scope.hasErrors == true`?

Comment: Yes, firstly I had that check, and then tried with ===..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have anything wrong in you code.

It has something to do with `Firefox`. It highlights that line, but it's not executing it.

There are some issues posted on the internet about step debugging in `Firefox`.

For example [THIS](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1003554) and [THIS](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1129813)

Comment: Yes, I supposed that it would be something wrong with browser, but really needed to check that. Thank you!